# BindingSource.Filter Exclude Values - How?

Tags: winforms, c#-2.0, bindingsource

My BindingSource is bound to a collection of objects (not using ADO.NET) and I would like to filter it and exclude some values but not sure if I'm using this exactly since the result set I am expecting is not coming back.  I was thinking something like this, but its not working:

```
MyBindingSource.Filter = "State = 'NY' AND State = 'MA' AND State = 'CO'";
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You've used AND.

If you want your filter to work you want this:

```
MyBindingSource.Filter = "State = 'NY' OR State = 'MA' OR State = 'CO'";
```

There is no way that something in boolean can be in two states at the same time. (At least in logic realms I work in anyway...)

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it outside of the WPF world, but you could take a look at the ListCollectionView (for IList)/BindingListCollectionView (for IBindingList). It should raise the necessary events, and you can use the filter without the underlying list.